# Don't want negative result of subtraction in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have the following code

```sql
CREATE TABLE dispenser(
    id_disp int not null auto_increment,
    location_disp varchar(20) not null,
    full_capacity int not null,
    primary key (id_disp)
);


CREATE TABLE records(
    time_stamp  DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    id_dispenser int not null,
    nr_pumps int not null,
    primary key (id_dispenser,time_stamp)
);

CREATE VIEW left_capacity AS
    SELECT 
        max(time_stamp) AS 'calendar', 
        id_dispenser AS 'dispenser', 
        full_capacity AS 'capacity', 
        (full_capacity-(nr_pumps*3)) AS 'available'
    FROM records r, dispenser d
    WHERE r.id_dispenser=d.id_disp
    GROUP by id_dispenser
    ORDER by id_dispenser desc;
```

and I have a problem on my view table where it says: `(full_capacity-(nr_pumps*3))` because if `nr_pumps*3` is bigger than `full_capacity`, I will have a negative available value. Is there a way I can make the value 0 if the calculation result is negative?

Comment: Note that queries against views in MySQL cannot access underlying indexes, rendering their usefulness questionable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `greatest()`. It returns the greatest of its arguments.

```
CREATE VIEW left_capacity
AS
SELECT max(time_stamp) AS calendar,
       id_dispenser AS dispenser,
       full_capacity AS capacity,
       greatest(full_capacity - nr_pumps * 3, 0) AS available
       FROM records r
            INNER JOIN dispenser d
                       ON d.id_disp = r.id_dispenser
       GROUP by id_dispenser;
```

Some additional notes:

- Do not enclose identifiers, such as column aliases in single quotes. Singles quotes in SQL are meant for string or date literals. MySQL might accept aliases in single quotes but other DBMS do not. So don't even start getting used to it.
- It is recommended to use the explicit `JOIN` syntax over the old comma separated list in the `FROM` clause. The former is easier to write without errors, to read and to understand.
- Your use of `GROUP BY` makes the query malformed. Not every column in the list of selected columns is either an argument to an aggregation function, in the `GROUP BY` clause or fully functional dependent of a column in the `GROUP BY` clause. Sadly older versions of MySQL or badly configured ones won't enforce that rule. But the results can be funny, so prepare to be in for a surprise one day.
- I don't know if MySQL might be an exception here. But in general an `ORDER BY` in a view is pointless (unless `LIMIT` is involved too). Unless the outermost query explicitly defines an order with an `ORDER BY`, SQL engines generally are allowed to return results in any order and will do if deemed necessary. So the `ORDER BY` in a view might get optimized away.

Comment: Thank you so much, really! I've been trying to solve this for hours and thought I had to use case, but it was much easier this way. Thank you for re-writing my code in a better way.